# Extracting information about a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What can we conclude about a square matrix $A$ if we know the following?

1. The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $f(t)=(t-3)^4(t-2)^3$ and
2. $(A-2I)(A-3I)^2=0$

Extracting information from 1) is easy but I don't know what to conclude from 2). Maybe something about the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $A$ is a root of $g(t) = (t-3)^{2} (t-2)$, so the minimal polynomial divides $g(t)$.

There are three possibilities, though.

Either the minimal polynomial is $g(t)$, and then $A$ is similar to either 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1\\
0 & 3\\
  &   &3 & 1\\
  &    &0 & 3\\
  &    &  &   &2\\
  &    &  &   & & 2\\
  &    &  &   & & & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1\\
0 & 3\\
  &   &3 & \\
  &    & & 3\\
  &    &  &   &2\\
  &    &  &   & & 2\\
  &    &  &   & & & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Or the minimal polynomial is $h(t) = (t-3) (t-2)$, and then  $A$ is similar to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & \\
  & 3\\
  &   &3 & \\
  &    & & 3\\
  &    &  &   &2\\
  &    &  &   & & 2\\
  &    &  &   & & & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Blanks denote zeroes.